# R: Find and remove all one to two letter words

Tags: regex, r

I am attempting to clean away any one or two letter words from a text passage. This was my first thought

```
gsub(" [a-zA-Z]{1,2} ", " ", "a ab abc B BB BBB")
[1] "a aaa BB BBBB"
```

I can see how the "a" is not replaced as it does not lead with a space and I can see how the "BB" is not replaced as the space it leads with has already been grabbed by the " B ".

Comment: `gsub("\\b\\w{1,2}\\b ", " ", "a ab abc B BB BBB")`?

Comment: `paste(regmatches(x, gregexpr('\\b[a-zA-Z]{3,}\\b', x))[[1]], collapse = ' ')`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can make use of `\b` word boundary and `[[:alpha:]]` bracket expression with `{1,2}` limiting quantifier, and then trim the leading/trailing spaces and shrink multiple spaces into 1:

```
tr <- "a ab abc B BB BBB f"
tr <- gsub(" *\\b[[:alpha:]]{1,2}\\b *", " ", tr) # Remove 1-2 letter words
gsub("^ +| +$|( ) +", "\\1", tr) # Remove excessive spacing
```

Result:

```
[1] "abc BBB"
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/pSOg1X)

Comment: sorry I am completely regex illiterate. How would modify the above so that `e e-commerce` does not become `-commerce` but `e-commerce`? Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `tr <- gsub(" *\\b(?<!-)\\p{L}{1,2}(?!-)\\b *", " ", tr, perl=T)`

Comment: thank you so much for being so unselfish! I wish I could upvote twice

Answer (score 1):

Use the below Perl regex .

```
x <- gsub("\\s*(?<!\\S)[a-zA-Z]{1,2}(?!\\S)", "", "a ab abc B BB BBB", perl=T)
gsub("^\\s+", "", x)
```